# How to use FormArray in Angular 14

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I'm creating a dynamic input in a reactive form using Angular 14. I'm getting this error:

> error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"controls"' can't be used to index type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'.
> Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'.
> 270 <div *ngFor="let skill of myDetailsForm.get('skills')['controls']">

And VS code is suggesting this:

> Object is possibly 'null'.ngtsc(2531)
> my-record.component.ts(7, 144): Error occurs in the template of component MyRecordComponent.
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"controls"' can't be used to index type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'.
> Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl<any, any>'.ngtsc(7053)

**My code:**

```
<div formArrayName="skills">
    <div *ngFor="let skill of myDetailsForm.get('skills')['controls']; let i=index">
        <input type="text" [formControlName]="i">
    </div>
</div>

this.myDetailsForm = new FormGroup({
    ... // other form independent controls
    skills: new FormArray([new FormControl('')]),
});
```

Please point out my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a getter function for returning the `skills` control as `FormArray`.

> my-record.component.ts

```js
get skills(): FormArray {
  return this.myDetailsForm.get('skills') as FormArray;
}
```

> my-record.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let skill of skills['controls']; let i = index">
  <input type="text" [formControlName]="i" />
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tn6loq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: this worked. accepting this answer